# Apple Script Time-Out "Finder got an error: Connection is invalid"

Tags: applescript, repeat, automator, finder

I have this Apple Script working with huge amount of data. What it does is pretty much compares hundreds of folder names to hundreds of picture names. If folder name is contained in the picture name .. it copies this specific picture to the corresponding folder. The data needs to be compared is huge.. sometimes it takes more than an hour to finish. I need an advice how to solve this specific problem.

This error message appears regardles of time and place where the script is executed ( my desktop or working server machine ). Usually appears between 40minute and 60minute.

[image]

As a result all finder windows are closed and the script stops.
Looks like it's some kind of time-out period.
Is there a way to extend this period or remove it completly ?

Thank you !
EDIT:
Here is the script itself:

```
use AppleScript version "2.4"
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions
property defaultColor : "Green"
on run {input}
    tell application "Finder"
        set MainFolder to (choose folder with prompt "ART.Numbers FOLDERS Directory:")
        set theArtFoldersList to every folder of MainFolder
        set NameOfMainFolder to name of MainFolder as text
        set targetFolder to "Users:zzz:Desktop:Pictures" as alias
        set pictures_collection to every file of entire contents of (targetFolder)
    end tell
    set userColor to 5
    repeat with CurrItem in theArtFoldersList
        tell application "Finder"
            if label index of CurrItem is not 7 and label index of CurrItem is not 6 and label index of CurrItem is not 5 then
                tell application "Finder" to set ArtFolderName to name of CurrItem as text
                tell application "Finder" to set elementpath to container of CurrItem as text
                set elementfolder to (elementpath & ArtFolderName) as alias
                
                repeat with anItem in pictures_collection
                    tell application "Finder" to set NameOfPicture to name of anItem
                    tell application "Finder" to set outpath to container of anItem as text
                    
                    tell application "Finder"
                        if NameOfPicture contains ArtFolderName and NameOfPicture does not contain (ArtFolderName & "_VIGN_N.jpg") and label index of anItem is 7 then
                            tell application "Finder" to duplicate anItem to folder (elementfolder as alias)
                            if label index of elementfolder is not 2 then -- пази червеният цвят на папката
                                set label index of elementfolder to userColor
                            end if
                        end if
                        if NameOfPicture contains (ArtFolderName & "_VIGN_N.jpg") and label index of anItem is 7 then
                            tell application "Finder" to duplicate anItem to folder (elementfolder as alias)
                            if label index of elementfolder is not 2 then
                                set label index of elementfolder to userColor
                                exit repeat
                            end if
                        end if
                    end tell
                end repeat
            end if
        end tell
    end repeat
    tell me to activate -- display dialog as active window
    display dialog NameOfMainFolder & " is Done !"
    return input
end run
```

Comment: Please show the script (or at least the relevant portions). Speaking generally, it's better to script System Events than the Finder for big jobs. the Finder is a busy app, and cfaps out much more frequently than SE. But without seeing your script that is only guesswork.

Comment: @TedWrigley You are right ofcourse. I updated the post with the script itself.

Comment: Is there more to this script that uses ApplescriptObjC? I'm curious why you invoke a framework that isn't used. Mostly I want to know so that I can decide whether to use AppleScriptObjC in a solution, or should stick to pure AppleScript.

Comment: @TedWrigley No, there is no ApplescriptObjC used in this script. I've been using this framework for some other script and it's left by mistake in this one. Sorry about that. It's pure AppleScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only been able to test the following script lightly, since I don't have access to your file structures, so please test it on **copies** of your data until you're sure it works the way you want.

My due diligence done...

The 'Connection is invalid' error comes from the Finder's `entire contents` command, executed on a folder with a lot of files. The script is timing out while the Finder is still plugging away trying to build the file list. It's generally a bad idea to script the Finder this heavily anyway; the Finder can be temperamental. With that in mind, I made three basic changes to your script:

- I shifted from scripting the Finder to scripting System Events where possible. System Events is generally more stable.
- I wrote an iterative handler which drills down through the folder structure instead of trying to gather all the files in advance. Thi breaks up the work the Finder has to do into small, manageable chunks.
- I put all the Finder calls into separate handlers, for clarity.

I also shifted a couple of variable to `properties` so that they could be seen by the script handler as it iterates down.

```
property defaultColor : "Green"
property userColor : 5
property image_folder : "/Users/zzz/Desktop/Pictures"

on run
    set sorting_folder to (choose folder with prompt "ART.Numbers FOLDERS Directory:")
    tell application "System Events"
        set sorting_folder_name to name of sorting_folder as text
        my iterateThroughFolder(sorting_folder)
    end tell
    tell me to activate -- display dialog as active window
    display dialog sorting_folder_name & " is Done !"
end run

on iterateThroughFolder(sorted_art_folder)
    tell application "System Events"
        set subfolder_list to every folder of (sorted_art_folder)
        repeat with a_folder in subfolder_list
            my iterateThroughFolder(a_folder)
        end repeat
        
        -- skip top level       
        if POSIX path of sorted_art_folder is equal to image_folder then return
        
        set sorted_art_folder_list to folders of sorted_art_folder
        repeat with an_sorted_art_folder in sorted_art_folder_list
            set artFolderName to name of an_sorted_art_folder
            set file_list to (every file of folder image_folder whose name contains artFolderName)
            repeat with a_file in file_list
                if (my finderLabelIndex(path of a_file)) ≠ 7 then
                    my finderDupFile(path of a_file, path of an_sorted_art_folder)
                    if (my finderLabelIndex(path of an_sorted_art_folder)) ≠ 2 then
                        my finderSetLabelIndex(path of an_sorted_art_folder, userColor)
                    end if
                end if
            end repeat
        end repeat
    end tell
end iterateThroughFolder

on finderLabelIndex(finderPath)
    tell application "Finder"
        return label index of item finderPath
    end tell
end finderLabelIndex

on finderSetLabelIndex(finderPath, idx)
    tell application "Finder"
        set label index of item finderPath to idx
    end tell
end finderSetLabelIndex

on finderDupFile(fileFinderPath, destingationFinderPath)
    tell application "Finder"
        duplicate file fileFinderPath to folder destingationFinderPath
    end tell
end finderDupFile
```

N.B.: Be aware of the often confusing path reference styles.

- System Events has its own file system reference objects (`disk item`, `file`, `folder`)
- Finder has its own file system reference objects (`item`, `file`, `folder`)
- posix paths (`/users/.../Desktop/...`) work in System Events, but not the Finder
- system paths (`Maintosh HD:users:...:Desktop:...`) work in both apps

If you want to send a reference from System Events to the Finder, use SE's `path` property (which returns a system path), then convert it to a Finder object in a Finder tell block. See my Finder handlers, above.

Comment: Thank you for your effort.You have explained everything very well.Even that some part i understand there is still a lot i have to learn and experiment with in order to look where the problem might be.The script works really fast now but unfortunately it does not duplicate once it reaches the if statement.I guess something before the if is not quite how it should be.I've made a screenshot explaining how it should work in a smaller data scale.Maybe that will help.[Screenshot](https://img321.com/view/image/16950d68-98a0-4822-81dc-1682423b6e55).Thanks once again for the effort !

Comment: Any further help please if it wont take too much of your time ?

Comment: I'll take a closer look

Comment: @OutOfTouch: I suspect (at a glance) that the problem is the `exit repeat` line. That was part of your original script and I wasn't sure what it's intention was so I left it in. But it will definitely cause the script to short-circuit in some cases.  try deleting that line and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Unfortunatelly that didn't help.The point of `exit repeat` in my script was to stop looking for files once the one with a name `ArtFolderName & "_VIGN_N.jpg"` is found.Since the script check them in the order they are possitioned in the folder by name it suggests first will be the ones with a `PACK` in theyr name.. and lastly `VIGN_N` ones. But even in my case sometimes it skipes files.So please when you have time before or after the Holidays...dive a deeper look.I am gonna use this script pretty much every day for months so if you could save me time i will really appreciate it.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but from the look of the image you posted above, you want every jpg with the same 6-digit prefix copied to a folder that is named after that 6-digit prefix? relying on file-order is often unreliable, and you shouldn't do it without good reason, but sorting by prefix is easy.  The script I revised above ought to do that for you.

Comment: @OutOfTouch: Hm. maybe you didn't see that I changed the script in the answer. I though I'd left a comment to that effect, but apparently not. Test out that revised script and see if it works.

Comment: Yes..you are right. Every .jpg file should be moved to it's corresponding folder based on the first 6 digits prefix in theyr names. I tested the script after you made the changes in your code and even now to be 100% sure .. but unfortunately it does not duplicate the files in the corresponding folders. Just displays that the folder is done.

Comment: @OutOfTouch: I'm sorry but if you need help debugging, you have to do and say more that "It doesn't work". The script works on my machine, with a folder setup like your folders.  If it doesn't work on yours that means ***you*** are doing something odd. I can't see what ***you*** are doing, unless you tell me; I can only what ***the script*** does on my machine. You need to be detailed and specific to a ridiculous degree or there's no way I can help you.

Comment: @OutOfTouch: Obvious things to check: Is the path in `property image_folder` correct? Are your destination folder names *exactly* the same prefix as your files? Are your files set to label index 7? There are only certain places the script will crap out silently (if an `if` statement returns false where it ought to return true, or vice verse; if one of the `repeat` loops receives an empty list because names don't match where the list is set). Add in `log` statements so you can see what's going on internally.

Comment: The problem was the files were set to label index 7 but the scripts goes into the if statement only if they are different than label index 7. So it was an easy fix. Now it works flawlesly and i am really satisfied with the incredible fast speed compared to the old version. Thank you again for beeing so patient with me ! I started learning AppleScript because of a script my colleague wrote for me and now you are doing the same. That motivates me and like in this example..there is really helpful information to learn how the lists work and geting use to some good practices.

Comment: I need some changes to be done to satisfy my needs in 100% but i will do them on my own. Wont take any more of your time. Thank you once again !

Comment: @OutOfTouch: feel free to ask if you run into any problems. I'm happy to help.